# How to filter for ManytoManyField in generic class-based views

Tags: python, django, datetime, manytomanyfield, weekday

I am trying to filter the queryset for when my model has today's day(like Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc). I made the weekday as a manytomanyfield in my model so that the user could choose multiple weekdays for a single instance of the model. I know the code below for my views is messy, but I hope you guys get it:

```
    today = datetime.date.today()
    today_weekday = 0
    if today.weekday() == '0':
        today_weekday = 'Monday'
    if today.weekday() == '1':
        today_weekday = 'Tuesday'
    if today.weekday() == '2':
        today_weekday = 'Wednesday'
    if today.weekday() == '3':
        today_weekday = 'Thursday'
    if today.weekday() == '4':
        today_weekday = 'Friday'

    queryset = queryset.filter(agent__user=user).filter(
        class_start_date__lte=today,
        class_end_date__gte=today,
    ).filter(weekday=today_weekday)
```

The part I am having trouble with is the last part `.filter(weekday=today_weekday)`. `weekday` is the manytomanyfield in my model, and I want to check if today's weekday matches one of the weekdays in the model. I hope you guys can help me with this problem. I am sure there are better ways to do it, but I hope you guys can help me fix the `.filter(weekday=today_weekday)` first, so it is at least functional. Thanks a lot!

Here is the part of the model referenced in the above view:

```
weekday = models.ManyToManyField('Weekday', help_text='Select weekdays for the student')
```

Also, the objects within this `Weekday` model is simply:
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday

Comment: Can you share the model as well for the queryset being used? Also its related models in question

Comment: I edited the question above for your reference.

Comment: According to this : weekday = models.ManyToManyField('Weekday') im assuming Weekday is the model and it has fields Monday , Tuesday etc? So in that case you should check the pk value on each field in your filter. I can help with the code if you could add Weekday model as well